# Is there benefit to a Windows-Identity-Foundation (or related) tag here?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked this question, and in the interest of searchability and the like, I'm curious if there's interest/benefit in using a tag for this feature.

> [Issues installing Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) on Docker Server Core 2016](https://serverfault.com/questions/849969/issues-installing-windows-identity-foundation-wif-on-docker-server-core-2016)

The tag on SO:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wif

Not having the tag on existing questions does make it harder to look for questions that may need to be tagged with the "new" tag if we implement it. But some other questions that would benefit:

[Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) application + ADFS 2.0 on Classic pipeline mode - Is it possible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/276736/windows-identity-foundation-wif-application-adfs-2-0-on-classic-pipeline-mod)

[PKI infrastructure and usage question](https://serverfault.com/questions/186711/pki-infrastructure-and-usage-question/186715)

eh... [AD FS 2.0 install on Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/645351/ad-fs-2-0-install-on-server-2008-r2)

Like I say, not a lot of benefit, but it does get a bit of an ask on SO so I figure it's worth seeing if the site here wants to add the tag too.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a new tag [windows-identity](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-identity). Unfortunately, using `windows-identity-foundation` was impossible due to the tag length restriction of 25 characters. Also, I am reluctant to create a synonym tag named `wif` due to the likely confusion with [wifi](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wifi).

Comment: "indentity"... typo, or has Microsoft started a new phase in the tabs-v-spaces war?  (grin)